# How to compare two sorted OrderedMaps to look for the highest values in each map?

Tags: java, hashmap, java-stream

I have 2 sorted OrderedMaps (I am using apache commons to iterate more easily).  I've used stream() to sort in reverse order based on the Key values, such that fisrtKey() returns the highest entry.  Between the two sorted Maps, I am interested which Key or Keys ranks highest between the two.  Here are code examples:

```
OrderedMap<String, Double> sum = sumMap.entrySet()
                .stream()
                .sorted((Map.Entry.<String, Double>comparingByValue().reversed()))
                .collect(Collectors.toMap(Map.Entry::getKey, Map.Entry::getValue, (e1, e2) -> e1, LinkedMap::new));
OrderedMap<String, Double> highRat = highRatio.entrySet()
                .stream()
                .sorted((Map.Entry.<String, Double>comparingByValue().reversed()))
                .collect(Collectors.toMap(Map.Entry::getKey, Map.Entry::getValue, (e1, e2) -> e1, LinkedMap::new));
```

To be clear, both Maps contain the exact same Key entries, they are just ordered differently based on values.  I'm interested in finding, between the two maps, which Key or Keys are the highest when compared to the position on both maps.  The values are not as important as the Key(s).  I've thought about converting to ArrayList, but outside of that, I'm stuck:

```
List<String> sumKeys = new ArrayList<>(sum.keySet());
List<String> highRatKeys = new ArrayList<>(highRat.keySet());
```

Thanks so much!

Comment: I'm a little bit confused. You're mixing keys and values in here. "order based on the Key values" suggests that you used `comapringByKey`, while in the code you got `comparingByValue`. `firstKey` returns the highest key or highest value? Which one do you want to find?

Comment: Yeah, I wasn't clear.  I sorted the Maps based on Values.  So in either Map, if I wanted the String associated with the highest "sum" or "highrat" value I just call firstkey().  But between both maps, I'd like to find which Key or Keys is ranked highest in both sum and highrat maps.

Comment: *which Key or Keys is ranked highest in both sum and highrat maps* and why if calling `firstKey()` on both these ordered maps not solving what you need? Its sttill unclear to me.

Comment: Each map contains the same keys, only they are ordered differently based on "sum" in one and "highRat" in the other.  If I call sum.firstKey(); I get the key of the sum map with the highest value.  If I call highRat.firstKey(); I get the key of the corresponding highest value in highRat.  These aren't necessarily the same Key though.  So I am interested in finding the one key that has the highest position in both maps.

Comment: @shuzDoc do you mean to find the key for which the average rank of the key is highest as compared to other keys (their average of ranks)? Your question title or context is no way close to that. (if yes)

Comment: So what is your result for these entries? `sum :{C=187.0, B=46.0, A=23.0}` and `highRat: {A=76.0, B=49.0, C=17.0}`